# top-level const with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, const-correctness

Suppose that I have class which has `std::vector<Object*>`

Should method like:

```
const std::vector<Object*> getSth() const
{
    return class_member_vector;
}
```

be converted to:

```
std::vector<Object*> getSth() const
{
    return class_member_vector;
}
```

It is always safe and should be always corrected in that way?

Comment: The `const` in the first example doesn't really offer any benefit. But on the subject of safety, it depends what `std::vector<Object*>` represents.

Comment: Since you are returning by value, the `const` in the return of the first snippet has no effect.  Depending on your design you may want to change it to something like `const std::vector<const Object*>& getSth() const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use the second variant for clarity. And yes, this is always safe. In both variants you are returning the return value *by value*, so the class cannot be affected by modifying the returned vector. Also in both cases the callee can modify the objects pointed to by the vector elements, so the outer `const` does not make a difference there either.

The `const` in the first variant is misleading and should be removed.

But you may want to consider to return a `const std::vector<Object*>&` reference for performance reasons. It depends on your use model of the class (e.g. lifetime, scope) whether this is a good idea or not. Performance wise it is a good idea to return by const reference since all STL containers make deep-copies which are rather costly.